# Build tool 31.0.0 is missing DX (react-native android)(Jenkins)

Tags: android, react-native, jenkins, gradle

When I run the following command:

```
 ./gradlew bundleStageRelease
```

This works fine and creates a bundle when I run it through my local terminal. But when I run the same command through jenkins, it throws me the following error:

```
Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/31.0.0/dx
File /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/31.0.0/dx
```

I had done the **d8** to **dx** changes when I updated to compileSdk 31, but not sure why I am getting this in jenkins again.